# Sign S/Mime message with Sha-1 and certificate in Delphi

Tags: delphi, certificate, delphi-2007, sha1, sign

Context: Delphi 2007

I am about to send an S/MIME message. There is a certificate which shall be used to sign the message. Also have a certificate which I guess includes the key(s) needed to do the signing. Sha1 should be used

I have seen some sha1 code examples, and a few examples that deals with certs/keys but not really a good one combining them.

I see for myself something nice and easy like the code below

```
someObj = new SomeObj("key/cert", "sha-1");    
hashedMessage = so.Hash("orignal message");
```